# Inserting Rebus message into SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: rebus

I would like to use Rebus for integration with third-party application by adding triggers to that application's database so the triggers would insert records in format of Rebus message containing information about changes in database (operation type: insert, update, delete, table name and row id). Tell me please is there some way to do this easily or I would need to create stored procedure myself by looking into https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Transports/Sql/SqlServerMessageQueue.cs Send method?

Alternatively I could just fire the exe with parameters from the trigger but it is not transactional.

Also I've seen this issue https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/119 but I guess it's dead idea.

Maybe there is other recommended approach?

**Update:** I just realized body of Rebus message is serialized so it would be insane to do that in SQL (and even not possible without SQL-CLR) so maybe the only way would be to create custom transport with ReceiveMessage method accepting messages in my own format?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had excellent results integrating with "stuff happening in SQL Server" by using SQL Server Service Broker - not directly (i.e. as a Rebus transport implementation), but as a message queue that I could poll from the outside.

Whenever something interesting happened in the database, a trigger would query some tables and select the result set out [`for xml auto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx) into an XML message that would be sent to a service broker queue.

I then had a Rebus endpoint with a `System.Timers.Timer` that would poll the broker queue and `bus.SendLocal` the received XML as a string - this way, everything from parsing the XML and on would be based on Rebus messages, retries, and error queues, and the customary reliability that follows :)

Comment: cool idea :) how this xml looks like for update and delete? I mean in case of insert you indeed have new data to select, but in case of update would it be just difference to orginal state and in case of delete just information that deletion happened?

Comment: The data was trading-related transactions so they were never deleted, and we simply used a status field to indicate if they were cancelled. Inserts/updates were handled the same way, so we basically made a full update every time something changed.

Comment: I'm wondering why you choosed to use Timer instead of creating transport like you desribed in issue 119?

Comment: After thinking more about it and discovering that rebus can use different serializers I think I could use normal sql transport as my throuput is low so it should be enough. I just need to add xml serializer to rebus and use it in order to let db create messages. Does it sound sensible? :)

Comment: I chose the `System.Timers.Timer` because I basically just needed to poll the DB for new broker messages, and I know how much work goes into creating a full Rebus transport ;)

Comment: No, seriously - pretending that my broker connector was a "real" Rebus transport would not be proper, because either a) I would have to put in a lot of work to make it a real transport, or b) it would not be capable of working as an actual transport

Comment: [#119](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/119) was about creating a fully-fledged transport, but in my case the nature of the problem was more of an integration problem

Comment: Also, it turned out that the service broker forces you to have both a sender and a receiver queue, and then - when/if an error occurs, e.g. with posting messages that aren't XML etc - a message is put into the sender queue. In other words, it's best if you also periodically pump this sender queue for error messages in addition to receiving the real messages

Comment: Regarding your plan of using SQL Server and XML serializer - that would probably work fine :) not my preferred approach, but otoh I'm almost always using MSMQ as the transport, so I treat all interfacing with other kinds of transports as an integration scenario

Comment: thank you for another great input :) Just to justify my decision I want to avoid learning curve and potential problems of SB. Polling manually and SendLocal from table would be more intergrat-ish but since sql transport do that for me, it seems sane to use it :)